# No accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments - Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this chunk of code

```
Dim _timer As System.Threading.Timer

Public Sub RunTimer2()
    _timer = New System.Threading.Timer(onSave(), 
                         Nothing, 
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),     
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
End Sub
```

and I get error *Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.* for the line where I am trying to create the timer. Although I can see in the documentation in msdn and in the libraries that it has those 4 possible types parameters that I use. 
I don't get it...

Comment: change "onSave()," to "AddressOf onSave,"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not passing a delegate to the `onSave` function.  You are calling the `onSave` function and passing it's return value to the `Timer` constructor.  You need to create the delegate to the function and pass that, like this:

```
Dim _timer As System.Threading.Timer

Public Sub RunTimer2()
    _timer = New System.Threading.Timer(New TimerCallback(AddressOf onSave), 
                         Nothing, 
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),     
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
End Sub
```

Or, VB will automatically figure out the delegate type for you if you just do this:

```
Dim _timer As System.Threading.Timer

Public Sub RunTimer2()
    _timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf onSave, 
                         Nothing, 
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),     
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To declare a timer in vb.net you can:

```
  Private MyTimer As System.Threading.Timer

  MyTimer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyTimer_Tick, Nothing, RunEveryNMinutes * 60000, RunEveryNMinutes * 60000)

Private Sub MyTimer_Tick(ByVal state As Object)
    WriteEventLog("Timertick")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That starts the timer after 5 seconds and calls it every 5 seconds

```
Private timer As System.Threading.Timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf DoWhatever, Nothing, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0), New TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0))

Private Sub dowhatever(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
   ' Do stuff
End Sub
```